# Angular 4 get local JSON File

Tags: json, angular

I have searched 3 Hours and cant solved the problem. So i hope one of you know how i can fix it. I develope

First the code:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  user: string[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.http.get('./src/assets/dummy-response/authentication/login.dummy.json').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the user infos  from the JSON response
      this.user = data['user'];
      console.log(data);
    });
    this.http.get('').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the login_success from the JSON response
      this.isLoggedIn = data['login_success'];
      console.log(data);
    },
  err => {
    console.log('ALARM');
  });
  }
}
console.log('HALLOOOO');
```

The error code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGsDn.png)

directories structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLXKX.png)

So my question is, how can i access this file in assets/dummy-response/authentication/login.dummy.json?
I use the router from Angular and i think, thats the problem, that they dont let me pass.

Comment: can you access the json  by typing its url in a new tab ?

Comment: Please, do not post code as image, prefer copy/pasting it instead.

Comment: I think the path of your json file is incorrect. Can you post your directories structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when angular is compiled, the path for your json will be

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/dummy-response/authentication/login.dummy.json
```

not `http://localhost:4200/src/assets/dummy-response/authentication/login.dummy.json`

so your get request needs to be as following:

```
this.http.get('assets/dummy-response/authentication/login.dummy.json').subscribe(data => {
  // Read the user infos  from the JSON response
  this.user = data['user'];
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myData;

/* Read the file, and pass it to your callback*/
fs.readFile('./myjsondataFile.json', handleJSONFile);
var handleJSONFile = function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
     throw err;
 }
 myData= JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Comment: add this "declare var require: any;" on top

Comment: ok install typeings : "npm install @types/node" it should work now

Comment: what is your typescript version??